# VS2015 Web Addin Project - Change web server physical path?

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015, web-config, office-js

I'm working on a Excel Web Addin in VS2015.

VS creates 2 projects, one of which is a web project, which I'm not too familiar with.

I want to specify a different root physical path for the project (ie, in ./dist or ./build).

I read some where that this is configured in `applicationhost.config` in the `.vs` folder.

I need to add the project to version control. My understanding is that `.vs` folders are not usually version controlled.

So my question:

Is applicationhost.config the only way for me to specify a different web server path for my project? Or is there a setting inside the project that I can use? ie, Web.config? which I can add to version control?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first project is your add-in's manifest. This is the XML file that instructs the Office host where to load your add-in from, how to render it in the ribbon, etc.

The second project is an ASP.NET web application. This is the add-in itself. All of your add-in's UX and logic reside here.

When you publish an add-in to the Office Store, you are only publishing the manifest file. You would host the web application just like any other public facing web site.

Visual Studio should handle checking in/out the files in project for you (or commit/push/pull if your using a Git style repo). The default directory structure for Visual Studio projects is [Solution Folder] -> [Project Folders] -> [Project Files/Folders].

You can move this around if you like but generally this is more work than it's worth. It also can cause some odd issues in solutions like this where you have two projects that depend on each other. If you still want to reorg your structure, you can do that by editing the solution file (.sln). These are just XML files so any text editor will work.

As an aside, I would highly suggest switching to Visual Studio 2017. VS2017 was a major step up in terms of features and performance and there is a free Community Edition available.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm trying to configure my sln/csproj such that when someone performs a clean checkout of the solution, when debugging in VS, the local-hosted IIS server will redirect to a different location (ie, `./addinWeb/dist`, instead of `./addinWeb`). I'm hoping there's a project-level setting I can configure. Otherwise, I am getting around this with a build script (bound to before-build), navigating up to `.vs/config/applicationhost.config` and changing the path.

Comment: Can I ask why you are using a local IIS server instead of the built in IIS Express server?

Comment: I may be mixing the terms here (local, express), as I'm unfamiliar with ASP.NET/IIS development. I'm using the default project settings as generated by VS when I create a new excel web addin. I simply need to configure the solution/project, so when I hit F5, the started web server will serve a different folder.